# What's the proper way to connect a non-blocking socket in linux

Tags: linux, sockets

I'm new to programming with sockets in Linux and have a question about the correct way to do a non-blocking connect.

I've created a socket descriptor and set O_NONBLOCK for non-blocking IO.  I call connect, which returns EINPROGRESS and then I call select, with a timeout value.

How can I tell how long the connect() operation will take before it times out?  Can I change this in my program?

If my select operation does time out, what then?  Is it normal to close the socket descriptor, create another one, and then retry the connect?  Or, is there a way to cancel the connect on the existing socket and retry the operation using the same socket descriptor?

Thanks.

Comment: Default connect() system timeouts are usualy quite long to accommodate links via a couple of dial-up modems, a satellite and carrier pigeons.

Answer (score 2):

When the connection completes, the socket FD will become writable. You should also check the socket's last error via getsockopt().

> How can I tell how long the connect() operation will take before it times out?

You can't, of course. You have to try it. The question doesn't make sense.

> Can I change this in my program?

You can change the select timeout, if thats what you mean. If it isn't, i don't understand the question. Note that you can reduce the platform default connect timeout of about a minute by this means, but you can't increase it.

> If my select operation does time out, what then?

You close the socket and do whatever your application demands for a connection timeout.

> Is it normal to close the socket descriptor, create another one, and then retry the connect?

Only if you have some reason to think you'll get a different result next time.

> Or, is there a way to cancel the connect on the existing socket and retry the operation using the same socket descriptor?

No. Once the connect has failed the socket is dead and must be closed.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell how long the connect() operation will take before it times out?

You don't. You have to decide ahead of time what a reasonable timeout will be for your needs, and then pass that value to `select()`.  I typically use anywhere between 5-30 seconds, depending on the type of network my apps are running on.

> Can I change this in my program?

Ultimately, no.  The OS is in control of how long it waits for the connect to timeout.  There may be OS-specific settings you can tweak to govern that timeout, but that would not be portable or recommended.

> If my select operation does time out, what then?

The only thing you can do is close the socket and try again.

> Is it normal to close the socket descriptor, create another one, and then retry the connect?

Yes.

> Or, is there a way to cancel the connect on the existing socket and retry the operation using the same socket descriptor?

No.

Comment: Thanks Remy and EJP.  Those answers help and sorry for the confusing questions.  The program I'm writing will run on devices installed in remote locations that have to make connections over unreliable networks (cell or satellite) so connections attempts could fail one minute and then succeed the next. From what you've told, me the correct approach when a connection attempt fails would be to close the socket descriptor, create a new one, and reattempt the connection.